# Passing timestamp to azure mapping data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, dataflow

I'm trying to pass last modified date and time to my data flow as parameter. Can anyone tell me what is a correct way to pass it as parameter. I've tried multiple things like. passing utcnow() from activity throws error saying file not found whereas passing directly from dataflow works fine.
I figured out using dataflow expression works fine for ucnow() whereas pipeline expressions fails.

Comment: Is the data flow parameter defined as a timestamp? Pipeline's don't really have support for date/time types, so the utcnow() pipeline expression returns a string. You may want to pass the string into the data flow and convert it there.

Comment: @JoelCochran thanks for the suggestion. I figured out pipeline timestamp format is different from data flow timestamp. Thus only way to use it by passing timestamp as string from pipeline and receive it as string in data flow and convert it to desired data flow timestamp format.

Comment: @JoelCochran It seems that you have already figured out. Would you please summarize your solution or idea as answer? It's very useful for others' references. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JayGong - done :-)

Comment: @JoelCochran well done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pipeline expression language is a different and a little more limited than the Data Flow expression language. While Data Flow supports a richer variable type system, Pipelines only support String, Boolean, and Array types. Since there is no Date or Timestamp types, the date functions in the Pipeline expression language return strings:

[image]

If you want to use the UTC value from the pipeline instead of the data flow, you will need define a *string* parameter on the Data Flow:
[image]

Then pass the string of utcnow() to the Data Flow as a Pipeline Expression:
[image]

In the expression, use the utcnow() function to get the string value:
[image]

In the Data Flow, use Derived Column to convert it to the desired type:
[image]